# Binary Tree: Why Does One Insert Method Work and the Other Not

Tags: java, oop, recursion, binary-tree

I just learned about binary trees and I tried to create an insert method. My first method did not work and I did a bit of tweaking. It now works but I do not understand why the previous method failed.

The method that does not work is:

```
if(root == null)
    {
        root = new Node(data);
    }
    else if(data < root.getData())
    {
        insertNode(root.getLeft(), data);
    }
    else
    {
        insertNode(root.getRight(), data);
    }
```

The method that does work is:

```
    if(data < root.getData())
    {
         if(root.getLeft() == null)
         {
             root.left = new Node(data);
         }
         else
         {
             insertNode(root.getLeft(), data);
         }
     }

     else
     {
         if(root.getRight() == null)
         {
             root.right = new Node(data);
         }
         else
         {
            insertNode(root.getRight(), data);
         }
     }
```

Any explanations as to why this is the case? Because the way I see it, root should be equal to root.left, so setting root to a new Node should be the same as setting root.left/right to a new Node.

Comment: what was the exception/problem in the second code? i dont see a root == null check in the second code. In this case you cant insert the first element

Comment: @JohnnyAW: in the first code he calls insertNode(null, data), this cannot work. But I needed some time as well to get it ^^

Comment: @user2776326 I think your second code is having problem because in case root is null then how it will get compared with data?

Comment: @ManuelM. i read it wrong, i thought the second code is wrong:) but you still cant insert the first element in the second code:)

Comment: nope, you cannot add the root node in the second code ;-)

Comment: Yeah, the root cant be added, but since int data is in the constructor of the Node class, when I defined the Node root object that I passed into the parameters of the method, I put in an initial value for the root of the Binary Tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first method, you would give null into your insertNode method, but no reference pointer. Therefore you set root = new Node() in the insertNode method, but the parent node does not know any of this, it still points to null.

Since this is some very basic Java understanding, I recommend reading some articles about "java parameter passing" e.g. http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand. So from what I gathered Java passes the value null into the parameters, so essentially we get insertNode(null, data), and there is no reference to the root.right/left. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you call the method recursively, `insertNode(root, data)`, you have to be sure that `root` is not `null`, which means executing `root = new Node(data);` creates an object whose visibility is limited to `insertNode` method.

If not, you can rewrite `insertNode(data)` to be non-recursive and create the `root` inside it if it is `null`.

```
public void insert(int data) {
    if(root == null){
        root = new Node(data);
    }
    else {
        Node current = root;
        Node previous;
        String from;
        while(current != null) {
            previous = current;
            if(data < current.getData()) {
                current = current.left();
                from = "left";
            }
            else {
                current = current.right();
                from = "right";
            }
        }
        current = new Node(data);
        if(from.equals("left")) {
            previous.left() = current;
        } else {
            previous.right() = current;
        }
    }
}
```